# iPhone display broken

Tags: iphone, display, repair

The display of my old iPhone 6s broke yesterday. I want to repair it by myself.

I've found many displays that can be bought on the internet but with a price of 30€ I don't think that these are original Apple Components.

Does anyone know if theres a way to get an original iPhone display without bringing the device to an appleStore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could buy a new (obviously) or used (probably this you want) iPhone and scrap it for parts (i.e. the original iPhone display).

Answer (score 0):

You can get high quality replacement screens from several reputable vendors (not Amazon or eBay). These usually contain an original Apple LCD with a copy glass on top. The various innards, such as backlight, touchscreen, flexes etc. will vary from original to copy depending on the supplier. You also want a replacement screen that was assembled with a cold-glue process (like Apple does) as opposed to a hot-glue process (yes, THAT hot glue!).

Of course, if you want a true original screen, then the options are Apple Store or buy a used device. However, keep in mind that the used device you buy may also have an aftermarket screen as probably 25% of phones suffer screen damage at some point in their life.